# Creating boxes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create multiple boxes along the top of the page using javascript. I have one box but cannot figure out how to get multiple along the top of the page. This is what I have so far:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>Boxes on Boxes on Boxes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boxes.css">
    <script language="JavaScript">
        el=document.getElementById("box1");
        width=window.innerWidth-50;
        height=window.innerHeight-50;
        el.style.left=width*Math.random();
        el.style.top=height*Math.random();

        el=document.getElementById("box2");
        width=window.innerWidth-50;
        height=window.innerHeight-50;
        el.style.right=width*Math.random();
        el.style.top=height*Math.random();

        el=document.getElementById("box3");
        width=window.innerWidth-50;
        height=window.innerHeight-50;
        el.style.middle=width*Math.random();
        el.style.top=height*Math.random();

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="box1">
      First box 
    </div>

    <div id="box2">
        Second box
    </div>

    <div id="box3">
        Third box
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS that I have:

```
#box1{
    background-color:orange;
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left=100px;
    top=100px;
}
#box2{
    background-color:blue;
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left=100px;
    top=100px;
}
#box3{
    background-color:green;
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left=100px;
    top=100px;
}
```

Comment: Is it falling over at those closing braces? You don't need them. Have you checked your browsers' debug console? You also need to do this in a page load event, i.e. after the box elements are created in the document object model.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Yes, changing 'box' to 'box1', 'box2', 'box3' should fix things for you.

Comment: okay. how do I make them unique?

Comment: Now the boxes don't appear just the words "first box", "second box" and "third box".

Comment: What are the random `}` for? I don't see any opening brackets.

Comment: I edited what I had to make some of the suggestions but it still isn't working

Comment: It's harder for us to know how they're supposed to look without seeing the CSS.

Comment: Now it comes up as one single green box with the words "third box" on it. Is it an alignment issue?

Comment: You also have errors in your CSS. Ex `left=100px;` should be `left:100px;`

Comment: @codeSpy - There's absolutely no need to load an entire library for such a simple amount of code, plus the OP isn't creating any elements.

Comment: All these answers and I still just have one green box in the top left corner of the page that says "third box"

Comment: @user2916725 Are you sure my answer doesn't work for you? Copy paste it in its entirety and try it. What browser are you using?

Comment: I need them to stay in one spot and align next to each other at the top of the page. That is the only thing I am missing now.

Comment: So you want them side by side, in order, but randomly positioned left to right, correct?

Comment: @user2916725 try this : http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/339Hv/

Comment: @codeSpy - a few lines of CSS hardly compares to an entire JS library. And the title is obviously wrong once you read the question. Nothing is being created. I also fail to see how you're coding for "many years later".

Comment: Just mentioned a better way.If you prefer using id for each control rather following a general way it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either move the `<script>` element to the end or wrap your code in a DOM ready or onload handler, because otherwise `getElementById()` won't find any elements because they won't have been parsed yet.

Then you need to include a unit (e.g., `"px"`) in the `left` and `top` style properties.

Also there's no need to recalculate the `width` and `height` for each box since you're doing the same calculation for each. (And you should declare your variables with `var`, but although good practice that isn't essential to make it work.)

Here's a working version:

```
    var el=document.getElementById("box1");
    var width=window.innerWidth-50;
    var height=window.innerHeight-50;
    el.style.left=width*Math.random() + "px";
    el.style.top=height*Math.random() + "px";

    el=document.getElementById("box2");
    el.style.right=width*Math.random() + "px";
    el.style.top=height*Math.random() + "px";

    el=document.getElementById("box3");
    el.style.middle=width*Math.random() + "px";
    el.style.top=height*Math.random() + "px";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m3Gg3/

Also the `left` and `top` properties in your CSS should use `:` not `=`.

Comment: What do you mean by moving the <script> to the end? Could you please show this.

Comment: I mean move the entire `<script>/*your code here*/</script>` element to just before the closing `</body>` tag, after all of your `<div>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>Boxes on Boxes on Boxes</title>
    <style type="text/css">
#box_group1, #box_group2, #box_group3, #box_group4, #textbook {
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;      
}
#box1, #box2, #box3, #box10, #box11, #box12 {
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
}
#box4, #box5, #box6, #box7, #box8, #box9 {
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
}   
#box1, #box4, #box7, #box10{
    background-color:orange;
}
#box2, #box5, #box8, #box11 {
    background-color:blue;
}
#box3, #box6, #box9, #box12{
    background-color:green;
}
#box4, #box7 {
    font-family: Arial;
}
#box5, #box8 {
    font-family: Courier;
}
#box6, #box9 {
    font-family: Tahoma;
}   
#textbook {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:red;
}
    </style>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        width=window.innerWidth;
        height=window.innerHeight;
    function boxes() {  
        document.getElementById("box_group1").style.left=(width-document.getElementById("box_group1").offsetWidth)/2;
        document.getElementById("box_group2").style.top=(height-document.getElementById("box_group2").offsetHeight)/2;
        document.getElementById("box_group3").style.left=width-100-document.getElementById("box_group3").offsetWidth;
        document.getElementById("box_group3").style.top=(height-document.getElementById("box_group3").offsetHeight)/2;
        document.getElementById("box_group4").style.left=(width-document.getElementById("box_group4").offsetWidth)/2;
        document.getElementById("box_group4").style.top=height-100-document.getElementById("box_group4").offsetHeight;  
        document.getElementById("textbook").style.left=(width-document.getElementById("textbook").offsetWidth)/2;
        document.getElementById("textbook").style.top=(height-document.getElementById("textbook").offsetHeight)/2;
    }

    function colorChange(field,group) {
        switch (group) {
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("box2").style.backgroundColor = field.innerText;
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("box11").style.backgroundColor = field.innerText;
                break;
        }       
    }
    function fontChange(field,group) {
        switch (group) {
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("box5").style.fontFamily = field.innerText;
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("box8").style.fontFamily = field.innerText;
                break;
        }       
    }       
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="boxes()">
    <div id="box_group1">
        <div id="box1" onclick="colorChange(this,1)">
            Orange 
        </div>

        <div id="box2" onclick="colorChange(this,1)">
            Blue
        </div>

        <div id="box3" onclick="colorChange(this,1)">
            Green
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box_group2">
        <div id="box4" onclick="fontChange(this,2)">
            Arial 
        </div>

        <div id="box5" onclick="fontChange(this,2)">
            Courier
        </div>

        <div id="box6" onclick="fontChange(this,2)">
            Tahoma
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box_group3">
        <div id="box7" onclick="fontChange(this,3)">
            Arial
        </div>

        <div id="box8" onclick="fontChange(this,3)">
            Courier
        </div>

        <div id="box9" onclick="fontChange(this,3)">
            Tahoma
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box_group4">
        <div id="box10" onclick="colorChange(this,4)">
            Orange 
        </div>

        <div id="box11" onclick="colorChange(this,4)">
            Blue
        </div>

        <div id="box12" onclick="colorChange(this,4)">
            Green
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="textbook">Textbook</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Boxes]

Comment: I have the three boxes now but I need them aligned at the top of the page.

Comment: Ok, the way you went about it is intrinsically wrong, but that's part of learning. You didn't want their top random then (that moves them up and down). I'll change it.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want First box, Second box, Third box along the top and in order. Then, do you want them randomly spaced or touching?

Comment: I also need to have the same amount of boxes down the left side of the page as well. Can you do that?

Comment: Touching, so that they are aligned the same just next to each other.

Comment: Let me know if this is closer to what you wanted.

Comment: Yes perfect, now how do I get them down the left side of the page too?

Comment: Now there is a lot of fine tuning that needs to be done to keep them from colliding or pressing against the side of the page, etc. The second group of boxes can be colored individually as well though.

Comment: I need there to be a group of three boxes just like the ones you made on the top of the page on the top, left hand side, right hand side, and bottom. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Do you want the side ones vertical (as I have made the left one) or horizontal (like the top one)? And the random positioning is necessary, right?

Comment: Every time I open the page they move to a different spot. I just need them to stay put on the corners of the page.

Comment: That's because you used `Math.random()`. No problem, makes a lot more sense without it.

Comment: I don't want random positioning I just want them to be around aligned around the top, left side, right side, and bottom of the page.

Comment: Take a look at it currently for the top and left and let me know if that's where you want them.

Comment: That all looks good. How do I get the boxes to align on the bottom of the page. What word do I use to describe the bottom of the page?

Comment: Right now the boxes that are supposed to be on the bottom and right hand side of the page are in the middle of the page. How do I get them to align on the outside right and bottom?

Comment: No I want a group of three boxes just like we already have for the top and left just on the top, left, right, and bottom.

Comment: Sorry! I also need a text book in the middle of the page.

Comment: This is perfect but there no boxes just the words where they are supposed to be and no boxes around them.

Comment: You mean around textbook (I just gave it a red background, but it's designed to dynamically re-position itself in the middle based on the size of what you put there). Everything else should have 3 boxes of different colors in four groups.

Comment: The only box that is showing up is the fourth box in orange. The rest are just the words without the colored boxes around them. I just copied and pasted what you had.

Comment: I just fixed the positioning on the bottom and right boxes (they were a little too close to the edges). I'll add a picture of how it looks in Chrome.

Comment: Along the left hand side of the page have a number of boxes with different font names in them. When you click on those boxes have the font of the text in the middle box change. Do similar sets of boxes with changes associated for the right hand side and bottom of the page.

Comment: Is the top supposed to do that too or not?

Comment: Across the top of the page have a number of colored boxes. When you click on a box the middle box will change to that background color. Along the left hand side of the page have a number of boxes with different font names in them. When you click on those boxes have the font of the text in the middle box change. Do similar sets of boxes with changes associated for the right hand side and bottom of the page.

Comment: Sorry! That is the full explanation of what I need to happen.

Comment: The top and bottom group work the same way. And the left and right work the same way. You may need to adjust the box widths to make the text fit better.

Comment: Not a problem. If your question is fulfilled, it's best to choose a best answer so new people don't bother trying to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand what  you want, maybe this?.

[image]

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var titles = ["First box", "Second box", "Third box"]
    var width=window.innerWidth-50
    var height=window.innerHeight-50-120
    for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        var el = document.createElement('div')
        console.log(el)
        el.innerHTML = titles[i]
        el.style.position = "absolute"
        el.style.border = "1px solid rgb(0,0,0)"
        el.style.left= (width / titles.length) * i
        el.style.top=0
        el.style.width = width / titles.length
        el.style.height = "120px"
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        var el = document.createElement('div')
        console.log(el)
        el.innerHTML = titles[i]
        el.style.position = "absolute"
        el.style.border = "1px solid rgb(0,0,0)"
        el.style.left=0
        el.style.top=(height / titles.length) * i + 120
        el.style.width = "120px"
        el.style.height = height / titles.length
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery :

Here the boxes should be created dynamically and without naming the id's hardcoded it also should be done in a better way with your code. It's easier now as you are creating 4 boxes, what about 100 or more. So it's wise to always take the better way to maintain scalability of our work.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="mainDiv">

</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
// general css for all divs inside mainDiv 
#mainDiv div{
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left=100px;
    top=100px;  
    float : left;
}
```

**jQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // taking a color array
    var colorArray = new Array("red", "green", "gray", "blue");
    // loop through as many boxes you want to create
    for(var i = 1; i <= colorArray.length; i++){
        $("#mainDiv").append("<div id=Box" + i + "></div>");
        //changing the background-color 
        $("#Box"+ i).css("background-color", colorArray[i-1]);
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/339Hv/)

[Here's Another thread explaining similar Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624302/javascript-boxes-changing/19625123)**,**
[And It's Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/27FHR/)