# Javascript boxes changing

Tags: javascript

I have to get the boxes to do the following: 
Along the left hand side of the page have a number of boxes with different font names in them. When you click on those boxes have the font of the text in the middle box change. Do similar sets of boxes with changes associated for the right hand side and bottom of the page.

This is the coding I have so far:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Boxes on Boxes on Boxes</title>
    <style type="text/css">
#box_group1, #box_group2, #box_group3, #box_group4, #textbook {
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;      
}
#box1, #box2, #box3, #box10, #box11, #box12 {
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}
#box4, #box5, #box6, #box7, #box8, #box9 {
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}   
#box1, #box4, #box7, #box10{
    background-color:orange;
}
#box2, #box5, #box8, #box11 {
    background-color:blue;
}
#box3, #box6, #box9, #box12{
    background-color:green;
}
#textbook {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:red;
}
    </style>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        width=window.innerWidth;
        height=window.innerHeight;
    function boxes() {  
        document.getElementById("box_group1").style.left=(width-document.getElementById("box_group1").offsetWidth)/2;
        document.getElementById("box_group2").style.top=(height-document.getElementById("box_group2").offsetHeight)/2;
        document.getElementById("box_group3").style.left=width-100;100-document.getElementById("box_group3").offsetWidth;
        document.getElementById("box_group3").style.top=(height-document.getElementById("box_group3").offsetHeight)/2;
        document.getElementById("box_group4").style.left=(width-document.getElementById("box_group4").offsetWidth)/2;
        document.getElementById("box_group4").style.top=height-100;100-document.getElementById("box_group4").offsetHeight;  
        document.getElementById("textbook").style.left=(width-document.getElementById("textbook").offsetWidth)/2;
        document.getElementById("textbook").style.top=(height-document.getElementById("textbook").offsetHeight)/2;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="boxes()">
    <div id="box_group1">
        <div id="box1">
            First box 
        </div>

        <div id="box2">
            Second box
        </div>

        <div id="box3">
            Third box
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box_group2">
        <div id="box4">
            Fourth box 
        </div>

        <div id="box5">
            Fifth box
        </div>

        <div id="box6">
            Sixth box
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box_group3">
        <div id="box7">
            Seventh box 
        </div>

        <div id="box8">
            Eighth box
        </div>

        <div id="box9">
            Ninth box
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box_group4">
        <div id="box10">
            Tenth box 
        </div>

        <div id="box11">
            Eleven box
        </div>

        <div id="box12">
            Twelve box
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="textbook">Textbook</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Will the background color of the middle box change on with other div background-color that has been clicked or only the font will change?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/27FHR/ you can try this. Something like you description.

Comment: duplicate of [Creating boxes in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623450/creating-boxes-in-javascript) This is fully answered there.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the task with jQuery which is more easier to maintain.Used functions to get desired data and manipulated them to create boxes dynamically.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="topDiv"></div>

<div id="leftDiv"></div>

<div id="rightDiv"></div>

<div id="bottomDiv"></div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#topDiv div{
    float : left;
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}


#leftDiv div{
   float : left;
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

#rightDiv div{
    float : right;
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
} 

#bottomDiv div{
    float : left;
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

#topDiv{
    padding-left : 33%;
}
#leftDiv{
    padding-top : 30%;
}
#bottomDiv{
    padding-top : 68%;
    padding-left : 33%;
}
#rightDiv{
    margin-top : -30%;
}

.changedFont{
    font-size : 20px;
}
```

**jQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//First declare an array of colors that will also indicate the number of boxes.
var colorArray = new Array("red", "green", "blue");

//Execute a loop to create the boxes styling them properly
for(var i = 1; i <= colorArray.length ; i++){
    $("#topDiv").append("<div id=Box" + i + "></div>");
    $("#Box"+ i).css("background-color", colorArray[i-1]);
    $("#Box"+i).text("Box" + i);

    $("#leftDiv").append("<div id=Box" + i+1 + "></div>");
    $("#Box"+ i+1).css("background-color", colorArray[i-1]);
    $("#Box"+ i+1).text("Box" + i+1);

    $("#rightDiv").append("<div id=Box" + i+2 + "></div>");
    $("#Box"+ i+2).css("background-color", colorArray[i-1]);
    $("#Box"+ i+2).text("Box" + i+2);

    $("#bottomDiv").append("<div id=Box" + i+3 + "></div>");
    $("#Box"+ i+3).css("background-color", colorArray[i-1]);
    $("#Box"+i+3).text("Box" + i+3);       
}

   //Define the handler for onclick events 
    $("#topDiv").children().click(function(){
        $("#topDiv").children().eq(1).css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));        
        $("#topDiv").children().eq(1).addClass("changedFont");
    });

     $("#leftDiv").children().click(function(){
        $("#leftDiv").children().eq(1).css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
        $("#leftDiv").children().eq(1).addClass("changedFont");
    });

    $("#rightDiv").children().click(function(){
        $("#rightDiv").children().eq(1).css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
        $("#rightDiv").children().eq(1).addClass("changedFont");
    });

    $("#bottomDiv").children().click(function(){
        $("#bottomDiv").children().eq(1).css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
        $("#bottomDiv").children().eq(1).addClass("changedFont");
    }); 
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/27FHR/)